# Python-Selenium: How to run tests in parallel when reading from a csv?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, pytest

I have a few selenium tests that I want to run, the tests involve reading from csv files, opening browser and executing the test. To reduce execution time I want to run these tests in parallel, I am using pytest and pytest-xdist, While trying to figure this out I notice the tests open multiple browsers with `pytest -s -v tests/test_storage/ -n 2`  command, if I am not using the csv file but as soon as I try to run the same command but asking to read data from CSV it fails with an error  `_csv.Error: line contains NUL`
Is it something to do with multiprocess or something? I have no idea how to solve this.

This is how my page class looks:

```
read_data.excel_to_csv(prepFiles.Storagefile,prepFiles.location,fileName=prepFiles.StoragefileName,
                       sheetName='Locations')
csvreader = read_data.getCSVData(prepFiles.location + prepFiles.lifeStoragefileName) # read latest csv

fulllist = []
def findStoreHref(self):
    self.driver.get(self.url)
    stateList = self.getElementList(locator=self.statesFooterXpath,locatorType='xpath') #list of States
    for state in range(len(stateList)):
        self.elementClick(element=stateList[state]) 
        stores = self.waitForAllElementsVisible(locator=self.storelistXpath,locatorType='xpath')
        for storeHref in stores: #loop through stores to get store url
            if self.getHref(element = storeHref,attriType='href') not in self.fulllist:
                self.fulllist.append(self.getHref(element=storeHref, attriType='href'))
        stateList = self.getElementList(locator=self.statesFooterXpath, locatorType='xpath')
```

and this is how my test class is:

```
@pytest.mark.run(order=1)
def test_Storage_site_csv(self):
    self.ls.findStoreHref()
    first_column =[l[9] for l in self.ls.csvreader]
    list_site_to_csv = [item for item in self.ls.fulllist if item not in first_column]
    self.log.debug(list_site_to_csv)
    assert not list_site_to_csv, 'Test failed. List is not empty. {}'.format(list_site_to_csv)
```

There are a few page and test classes in a Test folder and I am trying to run them as a suite. When I run the suite sequentially with `pytest -s -v tests/test_storage` the test runs fine. Its only when I try to run the test in **parallel** that I get the error.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. _Is it something to do with multiprocess_ - most probably, but it's impossible to help you resolve the issue without seeing the code.

Comment: Added code, I initially thought the code wasn't need as I can run them sequentially without errors and the error lies when trying to doing a parallel run.